# the styling rules inside my makeStyle Materiel UI not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, makestyles

I want to apply the `field` class on the `TextField` Components. but the margins do not apply.
My code is like below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Typography, Button, Container, TextField } from '@mui/material';
import SendIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Send';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  field : {
    marginTop: 20,
    marginBottom: 20,
    display: 'block'
  }
});


export default function Create() {
  
  const classes = useStyles();
  
  return (
    <Container>
      <Typography
        variant="h6"
        component="h2"
        color="textSecondary"
        gutterBottom
      >
        Create new page
      </Typography>
      <form noValidate autoComplete='off'>
        <TextField 
          className={classes.field}
          label='Note title'
          variant='outlined'
          color='secondary'
          fullWidth
          required
        />
        <TextField 
          className={classes.field}
          label='Note Details'
          variant='outlined'
          color='secondary'
          fullWidth
          multiline
          rows={4}
          required
        />
      </form>
      <Button
        type = 'sybmit'
        variant = 'contained'
        color = 'secondary'
        endIcon = {<SendIcon />}
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Comment: It works in this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basictextfields-material-demo-forked-xiu1l?file=/demo.js). Do you have any error messages?

Comment: no there is no error msg just it's not working

Answer (score 0):

On v5 MUI deprecated the @mui/styles styling solutions. On the [documentation](https://mui.com/styles/basics/), they put this message,

> ⚠️ @mui/styles is the legacy styling solution for MUI. It is deprecated in v5. It depends on JSS as a styling solution, which is not used in the @mui/material anymore. If you don't want to have both emotion & JSS in your bundle, please refer to the @mui/system documentation which is the recommended alternative.

And here is their new solution for styling components - https://mui.com/system/styled/

Comment: I've seen this message but don't really understand what it means as I'm new to programming.